# fileNotDound [Errno 2] No such file or directory while running python

Tags: python, subprocess, filenotfounderror

I am trying to run wav2lip locally on my system. When inference.py calls the subprocess it gives me an error.

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Wav2Lip\inference.py", line 422, in <module>
    main()
  File "Wav2Lip\inference.py", line 418, in main
    subprocess.run(command, shell=platform.system() != "Windows")
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\subprocess.py", line 493, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\subprocess.py", line 858, in __init__
    self._execute_
fileNotDound [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

**inference.py:**

```
    command = [
    "ffmpeg",
    "-y",
    "-i", args.audio,
    "-i", args.video,  # Updated to use args.video
    "-c:v", "libx264",  # Use a standard codec
    "-crf", "22",       # A reasonable CRF value for quality
    "-strict", "-2",
    args.outfile
    ]
    
    subprocess.run(command, shell=platform.system() != "Windows")
```

**main.py:**

```
    @app.post("/run_inference")
    def run_inference():
        """
        Run the inference on the video and audio files in the 'test' folder.
        """
        try:
            os.system(
                """ python Wav2Lip\inference.py --checkpoint_path Wav2Lip\checkpoints\wav2lip.pth --          face "test/video.mp4" --video "test/video.mp4" --audio "test/audio.wav" --pads 0 20 0 0  """
            )
            return "done"
        except Exception as e:
            return str(e)
```

I am giving video and audio file as an input and trying to run wav2lip locally to give a output video. But when inference.py triggers the subprocess call it gives me an error and program halt.

Comment: Is `ffmpeg` installed on the computer, and is it included in the `PATH` variable?

Comment: I have made a virtual environment and I have installed ffmpeg in my virtual environment. Do i still need to install this in my system outside virtual environment and include it to PATH variable?

Comment: Do you expect to use it outside of the venv?

Comment: Nope I intend to use it inside virtual enviroment.

Comment: maybe try `/full/path/to/ffmpeg`

Comment: BTW: if you use `shell=True` then it may need `command` as single string, not list of words. `command = " ".join(command)`